# Is it possible to create my own Watch Face on Apple Watch? Not compose from an official one

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, watchface

I tried to google it very hard but it seems blocking, I always end up with tutorials to change the complications and publish it for friends...

What I want to perform is create my own Watch Faces for my Apple Watch, with room for official complications. So I would be able to create my own watch face. Chronology did it, so why wouldn't we? I just don't find the documentation for that.

Please note, I don't want to create a "time-centric" application, I am here talking about real Watch Faces. My goal is to create something where the time only take the place of a small complication, with a custom design of mine, and then I have plenty room for complications from my favorites / personal applications !

**This question concerns the Apple Watch (And Watch OS), not WearOS.**

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: did you find any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Apple does not offer a way to do this.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> 4.2.4 Apple Watch apps that appear to be a watch face are confusing, because people will expect them to work with device features such as swipes, notifications, and third-party complications. Creative ways of expressing time as an app interface is great (say, a tide clock for surfers), but if your app comes too close to resembling a watch face, we will reject it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is Apple official Documentation about [how to add a watch face to your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/sharing_an_apple_watch_face)

> ## Support Shared Complications
>
> To ensure that your app’s complications appear as expected in the watch face preview, you must implement your ClockKit data source’s getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for:withHandler:) method. You can’t just add preview images to the assets catalog.
>
> Then, as soon as the user installs a watch face that includes your app’s complications, the system calls your data source’s handleSharedComplicationDescriptors(_:) method. Use this method to prepare your app so that it can provide complication data for the shared complications.
>
> For example, a weather app may provide separate complications for all of the user’s favorite cities. When the user receives a shared watch face, the app must be ready to provide data for the city associated with the incoming complication, even if it’s not already in the user’s favorites list.
>
> Finally, ClockKit calls your data source’s methods to populate the complication’s timeline. This includes calling getTimelineEndDate(for:withHandler:) and getCurrentTimelineEntry(for:withHandler:), and then calling getTimelineEntries(for:after:limit:withHandler:) if your app supports batch downloading future timeline entries.

Comment: @JulienElkaim was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?

Comment: Hello Jabbar ! Sorry I did not see the notification of your reply in Jan. Indeed no, but I think I am bad at explaining what I want to achieve.
This quote discuss about how to integrate complications to a watch face, but my concern is how to create watch face "models", so not using an existing watch face template provided by Apple but creating my own, choosing to put complication Y in the bottom right, complication X in the middle, etc etc